# Is there a point in using Unit Test, Rspec, Cucumber and Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I am beginning at Ruby and i read about different test methods/frameworks: unit test (MiniTest::unit now with the latest Ruby version), Rspec, Cucumber and Capybara. But I don't fully grasp what's the main "value" of each of them, differentiating from the other ones and if I could/should be using a mix of all of them to ensure our app is well tested?

Answer (score 1):

I personally use `RSpec` for functional testing and `capybara`/`cucumber` for integration testing.  `RSpec` is great for writing tests to make sure my classes perform as I expect them to.  `Cucumber` is great (along with Capybara, or webrat) for making sure my views perform the way I expect them to.

Testing is a huge asset to writing Rails apps.  It's amazing how often I'll change something and my tests catch that there's an unexpected side effect to that change.  It also helps you resolve bugs by being able to duplicate them in a test and making the test pass, causing the bug to be resolved.

So: `rspec` (and `FactoryGirl`) for making sure my classes do what they're supposed to and `cucumber` to make sure my user interacts with the web site in the manner I intended.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Factorygirl is reallu useful? how does it complement FactoryGirl?

Comment: So you don't use unit testing with Test::Unit? It's overlapping with Rspec maybe?

Comment: Yes, RSpec replaces Test::Unit, I like it's syntax and prefer its flexibility.  Factorygirl is great for mocking objects that you can run tests on repeatably.  Mechanize can also be used in place of Factorygirl.  Tests are useless unless they return the same results each time.  FactoryGirl makes sure your tests run against a defined object you control each time.

Comment: I see. thanks a lot. Is Mechanize part of Capybara? I'm not sure i totally get what does Capybara...:)

Comment: Capybara (and webrat) simulate the user interacting with your web site.  So you can, in your tests, click on links, visit pages, and test the content of those pages to make sure they display what you want them to display.  It's a way of testing *how* your website works as a whole.

Comment: Thanks just a last question, so can i use these in this pattern: use Rspec/cucumber for unit tests, capybara (or webrat) to simlate a user naviguation, and factorygirl to automate the whole process (i don't want to manually launch tests but that each time i deploy the whole tests are run)